# Navigation controller release crash app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, crash, release

I have a problem with release in navigationController. I have a map view with points. When I click on map point I create new detailViewController with detail. Everything works fine, but when I press back button my app back to the mapController and then crash. If I comment release everything works fine, but mapController is not release.
Here is my code:

```
FavoriteDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[FavoriteDetailViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"FavoriteDetailViewController" bundle:nil favoriteID:
[[(DisplayMapAnnotation*)view.annotation detailID] intValue] favoriteName:
[(DisplayMapAnnotation*)view.annotation title] favoriteCompany:
[(DisplayMapAnnotation*)view.annotation subtitle] favoriteLocation:
[(DisplayMapAnnotation*)view.annotation detailLocation] favoriteHtmlString:nil
favoriteJobIndex:0 favoriteTotalJobs:1 favoriteGeoLat:detailArrayData.geoLat
favoriteGeoLng:detailArrayData.geoLng favoriteFullUrl:detailArrayData.fullUrl
favoriteExportUrl:detailArrayData.exportUrl favoriteIdent:1];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

[detailViewController release];
```

Comment: I also faced this problem. I solved it by just not releasing navigation controller.Thats not a best solution but it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in FavoriteDetailViewController is crashing when it is deallocated.  Look carefully at the dealloc method.  Also make sure you set and delegates of the FavoriteViewController to nil.

Comment: Can I have a next question? Maybe stupid, but I need to know. When is call a dealloc method in navigation controller ? It's important to me because when I first open detailController it will use some memory. When I press back button, I will go back, but the memory is still used. When I open it again it will use next part of memory. When I repeat several times the following I spending large amounts of memory. In my opinion, dealloc method never be called

Comment: I don't know why, but when I made this: [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
detailViewController = nil;
[detailViewController release]; It works fine ... But I have still the above problem